# Why jQuery UI classes not working on table

Tags: html, jquery-ui

Here is my table, and using `ui-corner-all` i want to set table corners, but couldn't get it rounded.
Here is my html:

```
<table class="ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="width: 705px">
 <thead>
  <tr>
<th class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr" style="width: 35px;">
No
</th> 
<th class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr" style="width: 35px">
Description
</th>
</tr>
<tr id="3"> 
<td>
1
</td>
<td>
Informaton
</td>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

Why it is not working? I tested this class `ui-corner-all` with div, with div it is lookig good, why not with table?

Comment: I think you need to put it on the `TH` and `TD` elements, not the `TABLE`. You have to look at how the class works on the element it's applied to.

Comment: @Jared Farrish jqgrid has the same styles and this styles working for it, but why it is not working in that case i don't know

Answer (score 2):

You need to add **style="display:block"** to the table. For some reason the corners will not round on a traditional table.

Answer (score 0):

This might help: http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/